# How do you modify the value of a global variable, and have the global variable retain that new value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I'm new to coding in general, and I picked python as my first language to learn because a few friends said it was simple and fun. I decided to make a little text based game, and my demo for it went well except for one problem. I can't get the adjustments to health to carry over, and after tons of testing and searching I still can't figure out how to make this work.

```
def combat():
    global playerhealthpoints
    playerhealthpoints = 100
    def cavecombat():
        combatroundinput = raw_input("The round has begun. Do you Block, Dodge, or Run?").lower()
        if combatroundinput == "block":
            enemyattackroll = random.randrange(1,10)
            if enemyattackroll < 5:
                print "Enemy has missed their attack this round."
                cavecombat()
            elif enemyattackroll >= 5:
                enemydamageroll = random.randrange(1,10) / 2
                playerhealthpoints = playerhealthpoints - enemydamageroll
                print "You have taken %s damage." %enemydamageroll
                print "You have %s health remaining." %playerhealthpoints
                cavecombat()
        elif combatroundinput == "dodge":
            enemyattackroll = random.randrange(1,10) / 2
            if enemyattackroll < 5:
                print "Enemy has missed their attack this round."
                cavecombat()
            elif enemyattackroll >= 5:
                enemydamageroll = random.randrange(1,10)
                playerhealthpoints = playerhealthpoints - enemydamageroll
                print "You have taken %s damage." %enemydamageroll
                print "You have %s health remaining." %playerhealthpoints
                cavecombat()
        elif combatroundinput == "run":
            playerrunroll = random.randrange(1,10)
            enemyattackroll = random.randrange(1,10) * 2
            if enemyattackroll < 5 and playerrunroll <5:
                print "Enemy has missed their attack this round."
                print "You have failed to run from this encounter."
                cavecombat()
            elif enemyattackroll >= 5 and playerrunroll >= 5:
                enemydamageroll = random.randrange(1,10)
                playerhealthpoints = playerhealthpoints - enemydamageroll
                print "You have taken %s damage." %enemydamageroll
                print "You have %s health remaining." %playerhealthpoints
                print "You have succeeded in escaping the enemy."

            elif enemyattackroll < 5 and playerrunroll >= 5:
                print "Enemy has missed their attack this round."
                print "You have succeeded in escaping the enemy."

            elif enemyattackroll >= 5 and playerrunroll < 5:
                 enemydamageroll = random.randrange(1,10)
                 playerhealthpoints = playerhealthpoints - enemydamageroll
                 print "You have taken %s damage." %enemydamageroll
                 print "You have %s health remaining." %playerhealthpoints
                 print "You have failed to run from this encounter."
                 cavecombat()
        else:
            print "Learn to type, you suck."
            cavecombat()
    cavecombat()
combat()
```

This is my most recent attempt at getting health to stick, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to figure out! Try boiling down the problem to just  a few lines and post that... and exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Declare the variable outside of the function. Then reference it from inside the function using global. That said - I don't recommend using globals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` health. I am new to python as well so better to check around. IMO function inside a function is strange. Try to make the function separate and use `return` to retain the value.

Just to illustrate what I meant.

Following will `return` a `pl` value:

```
def cavecombat():
    combatroundinput = input("The round has begun. Do you Block, Dodge, or Run?").lower()
    if combatroundinput == "block":
        enemyattackroll = random.randint(1, 10)
        if enemyattackroll < 5:
            print("Enemy has missed their attack this round.")
            pl = 0
            return pl
        elif enemyattackroll >= 5:
            enemydamageroll = random.randint(1, 10) / 2
            pl = enemydamageroll
            print("You have taken %s damage." % enemydamageroll)
            return pl
```

The following can be done now:

> > > damage = cavecombat()

It will execute the function and then put value of `pl` to damage.

So if the print from above said "You have taken 3 damage. 
The value of damage would be 3.

Comment: Yes, this is better than using globals. Have `combat` return a value, then use `playerhealthpoints = combat()` to get the value outside of the function.

Comment: @JohnPfeifer I would probably end up giving the wrong advice. Adding a bit of code above to illustrate what I meant.